# Oracle SQL using while loop to select records

Tags: sql, oracle, while-loop

I am trying to write a sql for a table which storing geographic location data. That table has 4 columns - location id, parent id, display name and location type. Parent id will link with another record's location id in the same table and it may be null.

[Table Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I05gc.png)

| location_id | parent_id | display_name | location_type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | United States | Country |
| 2 | 1 | Texas, United States | States |
| 3 | 2 | Amarillo, Texas | City |
| 4 | null | Hong Kong | Country |

And I want to generate a report which have 3 columns: locationName,States,Country, the logic is like : while the record have a parent record, put its display name to States/Country Column based on its location type. But I have no idea how to do it using oracle sql.

May someone help me with this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxZKx.png)

| locationName | States | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| United States | null | United States |
| Texas, United States | Texas, United States | United States |
| Amarillo, Texas | Texas, United States | United States |
| Hong Kong | null | Hong Kong |

The logic will be like :

```
while(record still have parent id){
    if(location type = "States"){
       States column value = record's display_name
    }
    if(location type = "Country"){
       Country column value = record's display_name
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you just want a simple [inner join](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-inner-join/) on the `parentId`. This will only return records in both table.

Comment: @Icemanind Hi Icemanind, thanks for your reply, but there are some records have no parent id, so I cannot use inner join. And I tried outer join also, but I don't know how to select the value for States and Country column based on the location type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to do it via recursive query, but in this case, as joining level in 3, it could be done with a series of self-left joins.

Note the subqueries below used. First subquery `s` is deriving `state` at level 1. Second subquery `c` is deriving `country` at level 2. Third `c1` is deriving cities' country , with join with `s`, which would be at level 3. Then with case statements, you can get the desired result.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e22239082df9132b0c0790c8d1b8ff0e

```
select 
display_name as location_name
,case when 
    s.state_id is null and location_type='States' 
        then gl.display_name 
    else s.state_name
end as states
,case when
    c.country_id is null and location_type='Country' and gl.display_name is not null
        then gl.display_name
    when c.country_name is not null 
        then c.country_name
    else c1.country_name end as country
from gl
left join 
    (select location_id as state_id,parent_id as country_id,display_name as state_name
    from gl where location_type='States'
    ) s 
on gl.parent_id=s.state_id
left join 
    (select location_id as country_id,display_name as country_name
    from gl where location_type='Country'
    ) c
on gl.parent_id=c.country_id
left join 
    (select location_id as country_id,display_name as country_name
    from gl where location_type='Country'
    ) c1
on s.country_id=c1.country_id
order by gl.location_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using a recursive query. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=37896ed88a64c4e26757be2f9573e9f5) borrowed from Utsav's answer.

*CONNECT_BY_ROOT* allows to get attributes of the row used to start the recursion, so we can group by that. *CASE* returns NULL if the condition is not met which is then ignored by *MIN*.

```
SELECT root_display_name,
       MIN(CASE WHEN location_type = 'States'  THEN display_name END) AS states,
       MIN(CASE WHEN location_type = 'Country' THEN display_name END) AS country
FROM
(
  SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT(location_id) AS root_location_id,
         CONNECT_BY_ROOT(display_name) AS root_display_name,
         t.*
  FROM t
  CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = location_id
)
GROUP BY root_location_id, root_display_name
ORDER BY root_location_id
```